# confluent-kafka python client version is suitable for confluent-kafka 5.5.1 version

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Which confluent-kafka python client version is suitable for confluent-kafka 5.5.1 version? In confluent documentation it just mentioned to install confluent-kafka not the version details.

Comment: any help with this question?

Comment: Well, you can try it and tell us what errors you get, right? All modern Kafka clients are compatible with a wide range of versions